# Memory leak when executing nested C code in R

Tags: r, c, memory-leaks

I am currently working on an R package where time performance is critical which is why I am implementing  key parts in C. (I am used to C. At least for now I am not planning to use C++.)

In my opinion, the SEXP structures are pretty convenient also when letting C functions communicate internally. Therefore, in my C code, all function take SEXP's as arguments and return SEXP's. Of course I took care of balanced PROTECT's and UNPROTECT's for each individual function.

So far my main loop was located in R which called a C function over and over. Since this loop also computes some other things I wanted to transfer this loop also to C and wrote a C function equivalent to the R loop. Transfering this part to C now causes a major memory leak which I haven't seen before:
In each iteration the used memory rises and rises until allocations fail. The loop in C also properly handles the PROTECT's. It's also worth mentioning that calling gc() after canceling the execution does not clean up the mess of several gigabytes of UNPROTECTED SEXP's.

So why does this memory leak occur? Can R only properly clean up when returning to R? Are there alternatives to PROTECT/UNPROTECT when internally handling SEXP's, for example some kind of free? (I also tried rewriting the memory intensive parts to use R_PreserveObject and R_ReleaseObject.) I used valgrind with less iterations so that the program could finish before reaching allocation limits. No memory leak visible there.

To illustrate the issue, this rather silly code chunk in R works without any leaks:

```
while(TRUE) {
  eval <- .Call(my_function, argument1, argument2, 42)
}
```

Now calling an outer C function performing this loop

```
.Call(C_loop, argument1, argument2)
```

with

```
SEXP C_loop(SEXP argument1, SEXP argument2) {
  SEXP argument3 = PROTECT(ScalarInteger(42));
  while(1) {
    my_function(argument1, argument2, argument3);
  }
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return R_NilValue;
}
```

produces the leak.

Comment: The issue might be in the code, but you didn't post any.

Comment: You're right. I tried to illustrate the issue with some code. (Yes, I also tried these two simplistic scenarios without further evaluating the function results.)